# Run randomForest with many mtry values

Tags: r, random-forest

I am a new user of the `randomForest` R package. I would like to run randomForest classifications for iterations of `mtry =1,5,7`.

For example, I would like to run `mtry =1` 100 times and `mtry=2` 100 times. The output should show the out of bag errors for each run (100 results for mtry =1 and 100 results for mtry =2).

I only can write the code for 1 run, I do not know how to run the iteration of code with different values for `mtry`.

```
rf  <-  randomForest(class_name  ~  .,  data=tr,ntree=1000, 
                     importance=TRUE, proximity=TRUE, mtry=2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty method using the built-in `iris` data frame. The code below gives the final OOB error rate for each value of `mtry`.

```
mtry = 1:4
oob = data.frame()

# Loop over each value of mtry and store result in a data frame
for (i in mtry) {

  rf1 <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=iris, ntree=100, mtry=i) 

  result = data.frame(mtry=i, 
                      OOB=rf1[["err.rate"]][nrow(rf1[["err.rate"]]),"OOB"])
  oob = rbind(oob, result)
} 

oob
     mtry        OOB
OOB     1 0.04666667
OOB1    2 0.04000000
OOB2    3 0.04000000
OOB3    4 0.04000000
```

To keep all of the `ntree` OOB errors from each value of `mtry`, just change this:

```
OOB=rf1[["err.rate"]][nrow(rf1[["err.rate"]]),"OOB"])
```

To this:

```
OOB=rf1[["err.rate"]][ ,"OOB"])
```

Comment: Thanks eipi10. As I would like to repeat running for mtry =1, 2,3 (100 times) so each mtry should have 100 results. I used replicate function combined with your code but it didnt work. Please help.

Comment: The last section of my answer shows how to get all 100 OOB values for each value of mtry. You just need to delete `nrow(rf1[["err.rate"]])` from the code in the for loop.